# VisualForce - If Contains Or

Tags: visualforce, contains

I want to be able to render a form section if a picklist contains a certain value (value a) OR if it contains another value (value b).  How do I write this correctly?

Here is my currently working code to show value a if picklist selection contains it.

```
<apex:pageblock>
    <apex:pageblockSection >
           <apex:inputField styleClass="fieldset" value="{!Intake__c.Personal_Care__c}">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="pc"/>
           </apex:inputField>
    </apex:pageblockSection>
</apex:pageblock>


<apex:pageblock id="pc">
     <apex:pageblockSection >
          <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(!CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c,"Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom"), "true", "false")}" value="value a"/>
     </apex:pageblockSection>
</apex:pageblock>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate the different options using multiple CONTAINS functions in an OR function:

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(OR(CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Toileting'), CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Bathing'), CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'Self-Care in Bathroom')), 'true', 'false')}" value="value a"/>
```

There's a really handy list of VF expression functions here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm

Comment: This is amazing - Thank you so much!